# Shortlinks in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website where I want realise such scheme:

If user will type website/user1 I want to redirect user to website/profile.php?user=user1

But I want to redirect website/feed to website/action.php

I changed my .htaccess file to this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(/?)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^feed(/?)+$ action.php [L,QSA]
```

When I type website/user1 it works, but not works for website/feed, it seeks for website/profile.php?user=feed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the order of your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^feed(/?)+$ action.php [L,QSA]    
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(/?)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It means that if your url matches to the first `RewriteRule` it will apply it. Otherwise it will go to the next `RewriteRule`.

From [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> The order in which these rules are defined is important - this is the order in which they will be applied at run-time.